What causes, and how to avoid, finger numbness?
I am an experienced cyclist, but my partner is not and she has been experiencing some numbness in her fingers whenever she cycles more than 60 mins at a time.  This is normally on an upright city bike and any numbness is gone within 1-2 days.
We just had our first multi day trip (3 days where we were cycling between 80-100km per day) with around 5-6 hours cycling per day with breaks every 60 mins.
She was riding an appropritely sized gravel bike with butterfly bars (which we hoped would help offer some alternative hand positions to help with the numbness) but the experience was the same.
4 days later she is still experiencing numbness in both hands, but more in the left hand, and it is the ring finger that is the most effected, followed by little fingers and thumbs.
Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this or what could remedy it?

Try popping any rings off (as a medical need) and you massage her hands with a hand cream or similar.  Rubbing your own hands is way-less effective than someone else doing it.

Butterfly bars were the most short-lived handlebar type on my bikes (I gave up after two rides): the "normal position" (where the brakes/shifters), cause the strongest pressure on the exterior of the palm (position and curvature of the bar), which is where the ulnar nerve is. And also the most comfortable position (on tops) provided no access to the brakes. It seems to me that tourers with flat bars prefer flat bars with big bar-ends (Ergon GP5 for example), that are much more ergonomically shaped than the tubes of butterfly bars.

For me it seems to come from the shoulders or elbows. Windmilling my arms (one at a time) while riding quickly resolves the issue. Simply shaking my hands or changing grip position (road bike handlebar) doesn’t do anything.

I am not a doctor, but "numbness in the hands lasting four days" is not something to ignore. I strongly recommend not riding again until the numbness is gone; consulting a doctor if it doesn't go away; and in the future, stopping to adjust things at the first sign of numbness, not proceeding for multiple days as it gets worse!

The numbness can come from the nerve being pinched in the shoulder as well as further down the line.

Depending on the age and health of the individual, this could be early stages of peripheral neuropathy. Localized vibration could be aggravating an existing condition. It might be worth mentioning to the doctor, especially if there are other circulatory problems or diabetes.

For further reading, the term cyclist's plasy is relevant

Answer: the hand position is pinching the Ulnar nerve in the palm which leads to reduced feeling in the outside fingers.   If it were the thumb/index then it would be the Median nerve pinched.


Move hand position around a bit.  Your choice of butterfly bars was an excellent plan, but if the rider still grips the bar in the same way, won't make a difference.   You may be able to alter the angle of grip by changing gloves to a style with different padding, or by wrapping the bars with more/less tape in different areas.That cheap fragile chinese foam bar tape can be used first as a padding, then add a final layer of good bartape on top.  Added thickness helps if the road is rough or the bars are quite "thin" requiring a tighter-grip.

If it were a flatbar then grips like this can help some people:   There are many brands and prices but they all do similar, by adding surface area for that zone of the palm to spread the load.

Another solution might be raising the bars, so less pressure is transmitted down the arms.  Likewise, pressing harder on the pedals takes weight off the arms though this is a short-term relief only.

Personally I occasionally had this on a flatbar bike and a long ride where I was tired.  More rest stops may be a simple fix - a 80-100 km ride is a long long day for someone who doens't endurance ride a lot.

Perhaps a drop-bar would be more versatile than a butterfly bar?   The hand posititon on the hoods and drops is rotated 90 degrees from that of a flatbar, retaining the tops position for variety.   And now with flaired gravel bar options, the drops are part-way between the two extremes.As a low-cost test, you might try clamping some bar-ends onto the gravel bars to provide "horns" and see if that offers some relief.



Combining 2 of those ideas, Ergon make grips like the one pictured, with bar ends of a range of lengths built into their clamps. Even the tiny stubby bar ends can be good. It's important that ergo (or any non-round) grips clamp to the bars rather than just pushing on, to stop them rotating into a useless position

... or even a worse-than-useless position; the ones currently (but not for much longer) on my folding bike drift over time and especially with shifting so that my wrist lands in a more worse position than it would with round grips.  Now I can see the Ergon text in the photo, I know that has a decent clamp, also visible on a big screen.  Their GP2 and GP3 grips (I have a set of each) has the clamp on the outside end, with the bar end

Note:  This is not medical advice, this is anecdotal and based on my own and riding companions' experience.
There are a few potential causes of numbness of the hand and fingers, but the two I know of are restricted blood flow (short-term) and nerve pressure (long-term).  (Other causes might include vibration-induced problems, which may also be caused by nerve pressure, but I don't have direct experience to relate.)
Restricted blood flow typically causes the classic pins-and-needles feeling, and usually goes away quickly once the pressure is relieved.  Too much pressure on the heel of the hand, or too much of an angle on the wrist is the most likely cause, followed by gloves being too tight.  (Right now my current gloves pinch a bit at the base of the fingers if my hands swell up a bit on a long hot ride.  Short-term solution is to ride with the gloves off for a while, medium-term is cooler riding weather, and long-term solution is a new pair of gloves.)
Since the numbness is persisting more than a day after riding, however, I'm thinking that nerve pressure (and potential nerve damage) is much more likely.  Basically, her riding position is putting the nerve sheath, probably at the wrist, but possibly at the elbow, in compression.  For short periods of time this is fine, but it builds up and can cause permanent damage.  (I ride with a couple of people who have permanently degraded feeling in the little finger of one hand from this.)
Causes vary, but it mostly boils down to riding position, posture, bike fit, and amount of time in the saddle.
Ideally you'll have had a proper bike fit done, so that there aren't any major problems with the way you sit your bike.  For example, you don't want to be so far from your handlebars that you lock your elbows when you're riding.

Your elbows should always be slightly bent;
You don't want to be having to push back on the bars to keep your seat;
You may need to build up core strength so you're not leaning on the bars too much on a longer ride;
In all grips you want your wrists to be as close to neutral as possible (roughly middle finger in line with your forearm);
You want to vary your grip over a long ride - flat and butterfly bars may not really accommodate a vertical grip like one gets on hoods and drops.

I see a lot of less-experienced riders whose grip tends to have the wrists sagging or flexed on the flat part of the bars; try to avoid this.  (The one time I had to ride >50 km on flat bars, I rested alternate wrists by switching to an inverted grip for short periods of time.  Periodic stops to rest also helped.)
You may find that even butterfly bars don't help enough; there's a reason that road and endurance bikes have drop bars.

Great answer. I do take issue with this: "there's a reason that road and endurance bikes have drop bars." - This history is interesting ... I'm a flat bar believer for anyone that doesn't race ;-) - though obviously the majority of bike enthusiasts disagrees with me, so I'm probably wrong. :-)

I am not a cyclist, but an amateur medical researcher.  If you can't figure this out, don't forget to consider the neck.  Many (most?) nerves go through that small area and any abnormal pressure there can cause a near-infinite number of symptoms, anywhere.
Secondly, I remember being a thin kid and mowing the lawn with a very shaky gasoline mower.  I could see the blood drained from my pale hands afterward which were numb for a time after mowing the entire yard.

I'll answer a short way on the "how to avoid" part of the of question, as the other answers explain clearly the reasons. I think it's typically the kind of case where going to a professional bike fitter might help. It has a cost for sure, but there are also avoided costs in going to one.
The other answers explain clearly on what could be the causes, and what to pay attention to, but my impression is that less experienced cyclists have great difficulties in identifying to the signs that can cause a chronicle pain, and experienced cyclists who have learnt by try-and-error may not grasp all the interactions that there are between the different parameters.
The added value of a bike fit in this case (besides the expertise of the fitter): bike fitters have at least a standing bike where all parameters can be adjusted (and they also have a range of saddles), so it's possible to try the different "positions" when pedaling.


I am an experienced cyclist, but my partner is not and she has been experiencing some numbness in her fingers whenever she cycles more than 60 mins at a time.

I have had similar issues. The issues were not severe enough for me to go to a medical doctor's office, but the self-diagnosed cause is carpal tunnel syndrome.
Carpal tunnel syndrome often happens during night, sometimes waking you up with no feeling in a hand, but it also causes problems when riding bikes, especially if the riding position puts pressure in your hand.
Good health practices and an active lifestyle and weight loss have helped to completely eliminate my carpal tunnel syndrome for now.
However, if the problems are severe, consulting a medical doctor is recommended. Also a riding position with less pressure in hands could be useful.
